# How to avoid testing static method in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jsoup

I want to test a class that connects to an URL to parse html files (I am using Jsoup). The issue is that I do not know how to test this. I know that PowerMockito allows to do so, but I would prefer to avoid it if possible, by refactoring the code and test only important parts.

Here is the pieces of code I want to unit test:

```
@Service
public class EurLexHtmlToHtmlService extends BaseHtmlToHtml {

private static final String eurlex_URL = "https://eur-lex.europa.eu/";

@Override
public InputStream urlToHtml(String url, boolean hasOnlyOneSheet, boolean hasBorders) throws IOException {
    Document document = getDocument(url);
    Element content = document.body();

    Element cssLink = document.select("link").last();
    String cssHref = cssLink.attr("href").replace("./../../../../", "");
    //Method of BaseHtmlToHtml
    addStyle(url, content, cssHref);
    // Method of BaseHtmlToHtml
    return toInputStream(content);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseHtmlToHtml implements HtmlToHtmlService {

@Autowired
HtmlLayout htmlLayout;

protected ByteArrayInputStream toInputStream(Element content) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(content.outerHtml().getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}

protected void addStyle(String url, Element content, String cssHref) throws IOException {
    Document cssDoc = getDocument(url + cssHref);
    Elements cssElements = cssDoc.getAllElements();
    content.append(htmlLayout.getOpenStyleTag() + cssElements.outerHtml() + htmlLayout.getCloseStyleTag());
}

protected Document getDocument(String url) throws IOException {
    return Jsoup.connect(url).get();
}
```

}

The issue is that I do not know how to decouple my methods to be able to test without having to call `Jsoup.connect(url).get`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do it is by "injecting" something that returns the core object:

Instead of doing:

```
protected Document getDocument(String url) throws IOException {
    return Jsoup.connect(url).get();
}
```

You could have a static field:

```
private final Function<String, Document> documentReader; // fix the return type (Document)
```

And two constructor:

```
BaseHtmlToHtml(Function<String, Document> documentReader) {
  this.documentReader = documentReader;
}

BaseHtmlToHtml() {
  this(Jsoup::connect);
}

protected Document getDocument(String url) throws IOException {
    return documentReader.apply(url);
}
```

Then use the first constructor in your test, or add a setter and change the default value.

You could also create a specific bean for that and inject it instead: in such case, you need only one constructor and ensure that you inject the `Jsoup::connect` instead.

That's one way to do it without mocking a static method - but you will still have to mock the rest (eg: reading the url and converting it to a `Document`).

---

Per the comment, here is a sample with a Spring bean:

Declare a bean that does the work:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface DocumentResolver {
  Document resolve(String url) throws IOException;
}
```

And in your production code, declare a bean that use Jsoup:

```
@Bean 
public DocumentResolver documentResolver() {
  return url -> Jsoup.connect(url).get();
}
```

Have your consumer use this bean:

```
private final DocumentResolver resolver;

BaseHtmlToHtml(DocumentResolver resolver) {
  this.resolver = resolver;
}

protected Document getDocument(String url) throws IOException {
    return resolver.resolve(url);
}
```

In your test, when you need to mock the behavior:

Without using Spring injection in your test: in your JUnit 5 + AssertJ test:

```
@Test
void get_the_doc() {
  DocumentResolver throwingResolver = url -> {
    throw new IOException("fail!");
  };
  BaseHtmlToHtml html = new BaseHtmlToHtml(throwingResolver);
  
  assertThatIOException()
     .isThrownBy(() -> html.urlToHtml("foobar", false, false))
     .withMessage("fail!")
  ;
}
```

Of course, you would have to fix whatever you need to fix (eg: the type).

This example does not use Spring injection: if you want to mock `DocumentResolver`, I don't think you can resort to injection, or if you do, you will have to reset the mock each time unless Spring Test produce a a fresh container for each test execution:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class MyTestConfiguration {

    @Bean 
    public DocumentResolver documentResolver() {
      return mock(DocumentResolver.class);
    }
}
```

Then using JUnit 5 parameter resolver:

```
@Test
void get_the_doc(DocumentResolver resolver, BaseHtmlToHtml html) {
  doThrow(new IOException("fail!")).when(resolver).resolve(anyString());
  assertThatIOException()
     .isThrownBy(() -> html.urlToHtml("foobar", false, false))
     .withMessage("fail!")
  ;
}
```

Do note I am not knowledgeable on that, you will have to try.

This doc may: help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Comment: A couple of suggestions to the good solution above: 1) Instead of having a constructor just for test, keep only the constructor which takes the Function and make the Function final. Then, make a Bean for the function Jsoup::connect in production and inject whatever you'd like to mock in test. 2) The original getDocument throws an IOException that can't be thrown in a Function. Either you create your own functional interface ThrowingFunction and use that instead, or you will need to wrap the IOException into a runtime exception (but I'd go for the first option)

Comment: I totally don't know what Jsoup::connect returns :) I think the OP will still get the gist of my idea here.

Comment: Sure, me neither, I just see one single line of code in his method and a beautiful "throws IOException" so I just guessed :) But I enforce your solution, it's the way I would have gone and that's why I upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I do not understand what you meant by "fix the return type (Document)"

Comment: Oh simply that `Jsoup.connect(String)` does not return a `Document`, but a `Connection`. So, `Jsoup::connect` signature is `Function<String, Connection>` (I just checked the API https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect(java.lang.String) )

Comment: Thanks for you help, but unfortunately I am not able to test it. I'm sorry to ask, but could you provide a sample of how you would write a test with your solution?